# JXBrowser - Load PDF from local file system

Tags: java, swing, jxbrowser

I am trying to load a PDF from local file system in JXbrowser. The documentation on this page says it is possible.

https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000065675-displaying-pdf

The above url also has a sample code. But when I access a pdf on my file system by replacing the line 23 of that code with

```
browser.loadURL("C:\\pdf-test.pdf")
```

it does not load the PDF.

I am using the Browser in lightweight mode.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the url is not correct.

The correct way to load a file from the current file system is to use the `file` protocol:

```
browser.loadURL("file:///C:/pdf-test.pdf")
```

Comment: I tried that. It did not work. I also tried reading the pdf file into java.io.File and using its toURI.toURL to get the proper URL. That also did not work.   The PDF is displayed when I use the browser in HeavyWeight mode.

Answer (score 0):

There's an issue in JxBrowser 6.14 with loading PDF documents from local files. If you see that Chromium engine is crashed when loading PDF document from local file, then it's the issue I'm talking about. It will be fixed in 6.14.1 version.

Comment: Thanks Vladimir. I look forward to the fix in next version 6.14.1.

Comment: Is there a tentative time frame on when version 6.14.1 will become available?

Comment: It will be available for download this week. To get notifications about new releases you can subscribe at https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/discussions/forums/9000110576

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to inform you that we've fixed the mentioned issue

A new **version 6.14.1 of JxBrowser** with improved Chromium binaries extraction logic and quite a number of requested fixes is available for download from our web-site.